# Value Returning Method C#

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

i need help creating a three overload methods called GetPrice().  For all three methods, GetPrice() should return the price of one to three parameters.  If a single parameter is passed (price), default the quantity to 1 and no tax.  If two parameters are passed, price and quantity, assume no tax.  If three parameters are passed, price, quantity and sale tax percent (decimal representing percent), return price * quantity + (price * quantity * sales tax). Im new to c# dont really know much just want to know you would do this simple problem.

Comment: Do you actually need three overloads, or just one method with default parameters?

Comment: Have you tried something yet? Give it a whirl first then ask for help fixing it if it's broke. Overloads are easy.

Comment: Could you please try to the best of your ability and then post the code you used and we will try and correct any problems with it

Answer (score 2):

Three simple methods, assuming your tax is a double representing percent (i.e., 5% would be passed in as .05):

```
public double GetPrice(double price)
{
    return price;
}

public double GetPrice(double price, double tax)
{
    return price + (price * tax);
}

public double GetPrice(double price, int quantity, double tax)
{
    return (quantity * price) + (quantity * price * tax);
}
```

or as stated by @JonSkeet, one method with default params:

```
public double GetPrice(double price, int quantity = 1, double tax = 0.0)
{
    return (quantity * price) + (quantity * price * tax);
}
```

Comment: Or `return (quantity * price * (1 + tax));`

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it but something like this, that should get you going

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {

        public decimal GetPrice(decimal price)
        {
            return price;
        }

        public decimal GetPrice(decimal price, int qty)
        {
            return price * qty;
        }

        public decimal GetPrice(decimal price, int qty, decimal tax)
        {
            return price * qty * tax;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Or the more fun way, because you reuse the Methods: -

```
public decimal GetPrice(decimal price)
{
  return price
}

public decimal GetPrice(decimal price, int qty)
{
    return GetPrice(price) * quantity
}

public decimal GetPrice(decimal price, int qty, decimal tax)
{
    return GetPrice(price, qty) * tax
}
```

Comment: He did say tax percent as a decimal, and stated by his example of `price * quantity + (price * quantity * sales tax)`, it would be a decimal between 0-1, as where this code assumes it is more than 1 (i.e. 1.04)

Comment: Why would you `GetPrice(price)` when it simply returns `price`? That seems inefficient to me. You simply add more overhead to the stack in order to get a value that you already had...

Comment: VP - Yes you are Right, EBrown - yes you are right, I was just doing that to show how overloading could be used